# laravel - make a search form and show result in same page

Tags: php, laravel

in my show method in laravel i have a form that i want to submit and show the result on the same page so here is my show method first of all :

```
 public function show(Property $property)
{

    $property = Property::with('propertycalendars')->where('id', $property->id)->first();
    foreach ($property->propertycalendars as $prop) {
        $end_reserve = $prop->reserve_end;
    }
//             HERE NEW RELATION

    $pdate = Property::with('dates')->get();

    return view('users.properties.show', compact('property','pdate','end_reserve'));
}
```

and in the view of my show which for example is the url of a uniq property like below just as an example :

```
http://localhost:8000/properties/1
```

now i have a form to submit to search the Date table and bring me the dates so here is what i have wrote for the search function :

```
public function search (Request $request,$property_id){
//Send an empty variable to the view, unless the if logic below changes, then it'll send a proper variable to the view.
$results = null;

//Runs only if the search has something in it.
if (!empty($request->property_id)) {
    $start_date = $request->start_date;
    $search_date = Date::all()->where('date',$start_date);
}
return view('admin.properties.show')->with('search_date', $search_date);
}
```

and 
thats my route :

```
Route::get('/properties/{{property_id}}','PropertyController@search');
```

and finally my form to submit the search :

```
<form action="/properties/search" method="get">
            {{csrf_field()}}

            <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input type="hidden" value="{{$property->id}}" name="property_id">
                <input  name="start_date"  class="form-control m-input start_date" autocomplete="off"> </div>

            <div class="col-lg-5">
                <input  name="finish_date"  class="form-control m-input start_date" autocomplete="off"> </div>

            <div class="col-lg-2">
                <input type="submit" value="seach" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" autocomplete="off">
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
```

but now when i submit the form it returns a 404 not found with a link like below :

```
http://localhost:8000/properties/search?_token=R8ncSBjeZANMHlWMcbC6o5mYJZfwWgdfTwuviFo1&property_id=1&start_date=1398%2F1%2F12&title=
```

Answer (score 4):

In your controller, change to the following:

```
public function search (Request $request){

    //Send an empty variable to the view, unless the if logic below changes, then it'll send a proper variable to the view.
    $results = null;

    //Runs only if the search has something in it.
    if (!empty($request->title)) {
        $results = Property::all()->where('some search here')->get();
    }
    return view('admin.article.index')->with('results', $results);
}
```

This will send any (and all) results that your query finds to the view. Now in your view, you'll need to ensure there are actual results, or you'll get an error, so for example:

```
@if ($results)

    //There are results, loop through them
    @foeach($results as $item)
        {{$item->title}}
    @endforeach

@else

    //There are no results, show the form maybe?
@endif
```

Without knowing your table structure, I can't give the exact way to loop through your results, but this should get you started.

**Edit:** Since OP's question nature changed a fair bit from the original question:

In order to achieve the new flow, you'd need to pass in a URL param in the route, and change it to be a get, since you're no longer posting it from a form:

```
Route::get('/properties/{search}','PropertyController@search');
```

This tells Laravel you've got something coming from a `website.com/properties/xxxxx` request - the `xxxxx` would contain the search key you'd then pass to your controller to lookup. The `{search}` portion in the route can be whatever name you want, just ensure the controller's second param matches it.

If you wanted to allow for a posting from your search form, you can (in addition) add the following to your routes:

```
Route::post('/properties','PropertyController@search');
```

Then in your controller, fetch whatever came from the form via the [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/requests) facade.

Then in your controller, you'd check if this is valid:

```
public function search (Request $request, $search){

    //Send an empty variable to the view, unless the if logic below changes, then it'll send a proper variable to the view.
    $results = null;

    //Runs only if the second URL param has a value
    if (!empty($search)) {
        $results = Property::all()->where('some search here')->get();
    }
    return view('admin.article.index')->with('results', $results);
}
```

Comment: i am sorry i forgot to mention that i am already on the show function means i am showing a property now like the link here http://localhost:8000/properties/1 so should i pass the property id too ?

Comment: Probably should have included that important part in your question - as it totally changes the nature of the answers. Also, no one can see your localhost.

Comment: yes yes i just mentioned that now so  edit the question sorry about that :)

Comment: i just wanted to show you that i am showing a property that was why i send you the link of my local host

Comment: My edit should help - you'll need to update your route and controller. Without the exact eloquent query you're running, I can't make a suggestion, but this should also help get you in the right direction.

Comment: one thing i didnt understand is which part of that controller i am telling my laravel that go to for example number 1 property ?? i stock on that part

Comment: If you're using the URL (aka, GET) method, your controller will see the portion `{search}` from `/properties/{search}`. This is passed to your controller arguments as `$search` and can be fetched via `$request->search`

Comment: i did as you mentioned but i got the error would u mind take a look at edited and updated question ??